# Abbreviation,set restriction

Tags: probability-theory, discrete-optimization

currently I am trying to write a restriction based on a set that I have, and for some reason I have been struggling a lot.

So I have a set A= A1 $\cup$ A2 $\cup$ A3 $\cup$ A4

And the restriction I want to write is that a location lets say Y can be either A2 or A3 . (not both at the same time) How I can write that?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What you want is the symmetric difference, which doesn't have a single standard symbol, but a few common ones.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference

Comment: `$\cup$` makes $\cup$